# LIKE with wildcard (%) not working on 4000char+ clob column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

please see my below example. It seems that `LIKE` on a `CLOB` does not **reliably** work with wildcards (`%`) when the clob has more than 4000 chars, **even if** the searched term is in the first 4000 chars. In my example below `LIKE` works with `%` as long as the clob has less than ~16.000 chars.

**My question is: What is the rule? Is `LIKE` just generally unsafe to use on `CLOB` columns?**

Below I am creating 3 clobs that share the first 4000 chars, but have a different amount of chars added after that. When querying the first few chars with `LIKE` and a `%`, the longest `CLOB` does not show up.

```
create table test (col_ clob,id_ number);

insert into test values (null,1);
insert into test values (null,2);
insert into test values (null,3);

-- all 3 get the first part
update test 
set col_ = col_||to_clob(
'step A: 1514 JBPM_TASKINSTANCE cancelled. IDs: 647881560,649669434,646432837,649847575,685046256,682731832,696807202,729925679,754283519,1575869371,873593668,888156478,865437185,889938643,941358497,947331441,973924170,1004124097,956249253,985498887,993206349,1109217579,1113300475,1144065340,1121718658,1128874348,1132468962,1138225634,1161491440,1199842072,1167246496,1185675581,1185044258,1179241140,1201617298,1201620462,1271504575,1291166065,1192439215,3450764985,1223478198,1226377388,1255098113,1258049301,1269483039,1389172034,1538320916,1534506215,1275308781,1448218781,1289019720,1341518604,1327111775,1297656789,1359220594,1342185941,1441269423,1358786499,1346828156,1812130914,1369567075,1766470453,1406441839,1430601916,1382175115,1401183081,1417629193,1380436355,1415414339,1447863326,1383156946,1390952690,1407314398,1410736721,1392649751,1490242158,1410387508,1403002954,1424027725,1413554547,1421846137,1431616842,1413533036,1434584737,1419348181,1432340980,1408509756,1408521234,1448035789,1448042204,1447510642,1421788750,1427007414,1415789790,1813497522,1440200203,1416728688,1652058498,1695890932,1426493489,1444985100,1426494760,1442468948,1418941443,2517649728,1423975229,1424358396,1432004425,1432004499,1444254532,1435954215,1435940114,1424490615,1479853329,1449890691,1424864700,1447465392,1440758412,1427632533,1459066933,1429282077,1442449472,1443061577,1431582495,1489712417,1451975060,1452073020,1496841245,1471863494,1486875131,1450759726,1437070401,1440522983,1435627601,1481721692,1483418393,1449062035,1436139973,1446723840,1439503531,1438312481,1506528866,1449572942,1449571875,1444722671,1506587882,1506076622,1444646698,1444022457,1517968698,1464420387,1443390656,1444065109,1447437473,1446091008,1447437430,1446308056,1499707484,1498740025,1449389032,1750789625,1794298856,1782484488,1446636097,1490628913,1472680258,1450487454,1450483336,1463599647,1449342516,1526095367,1498416881,1510527772,1494010287,1510523510,1536736763,1449746866,1456217730,1480364649,1456832877,1456223078,1456227316,1462863514,1491518804,1456237182,1456228366,1451840612,1456239303,1456239233,1456242805,1482379025,1457093835,1452573038,1456245907,1462776168,1463785759,1473381464,1473379783,1496841626,1462781742,1462778861,1462779264,1463647317,1494655551,1494660729,1511313831,1500663718,1464338851,1488982535,1462781310,1471736830,1471750024,1471737562,1471738197,1471755185,1471755096,1471762795,1511568600,1466798095,1479747554,1479752363,1473570441,1537608976,1499412932,1499415480,1512243488,1480308307,1486666480,1480962849,1486665508,1481436614,1501550975,1486780904,1518187792,1486667712,1526232281,1506233646,1490557756,1578967963,1566489212,1490551633,1505341900,1487510242,1490021956,1490424078,1501501987,1501502117,1518190250,1511571712,1488221604,1493157335,1488347379,1490027853,1490031886,1490988765,1491232970,1503175011,1492093737,1496771353,1513769803,1497229557,1632815098,1508150446,1496424493,1496989437,1497872367,1498339923,1498416395,1515024054,1535110893,1715000701,1747199593,1716957407,1520608484,1498618849,1498864471,1500390533,1513243006,1500409850,1502229523,1503656100,1504535841,1504316349,1506022713,1505095606,1511200028,1511198587,1565677687,1507333027,1526174760,1505496278,1506674775,1515741966,1510036898,1520451282,1520457157,1511558322,1559020441,1548560372,1508297707,1526331083,1512341505,1530413597,1578882543,1598485601,1536307196,1517080210,1524922405,1527649735,1559014115,1609896003,1526296264,1547202944,1527617961,1652035189,1715005200,1529240326,1528138645,1528975612,1538130873,1538132407,1529421257,1530451370,1536562229,1545889137,1541450771,1569934159,1632816780,1536319959,1566300852,1536547612,1537623906,1558345580,1540471856,1557925618,1540301650,1575175744,1544301327,1542771803,1542884750,1574216870,1580479328,1557363359,1543677212,1569878359,1548402377,1547043476,1580579904,1552147778,1575411424,1557622105,1552352560,1582687415,1576265186,1552766622,1563207756,1552552879,1573948291'
)
where id_ in (1,2,3)
;

-- only 2 and 3 get the second part
update test 
set col_ = col_||to_clob(
',1553526018,1565235619,1557983068,1557388741,1563686317,1580283324,1577644453,1563216021,1569983475,1594070305,1635807479,1569896665,1601970391,1602285356,1598928800,1574005625,1593288801,1598668878,1571111568,1575242739,1573391009,1573685559,1574181957,1599930275,1602285355,1601979898,1812453186,1830844044,1572930315,1596453870,1652078234,1711545596,1801825083,1576109074,1574717177,1627592524,1574805822,1579689917,1582968490,1578921490,1579221408,1594857586,1607244162,1579574377,1579931414,1582141417,1580871080,1581011785,1594078626,1583289978,1594069017,1582028459,1807070553,1582081896,1598457272,1680620771,1661308597,1590557490,1583733791,1583969283,1584010015,1589261456,1585961214,1585441353,1585577145,1585947839,1609229336,1609226944,1589017730,1589791878,1609021392,1609337773,1612859899,1609313339,1590109680,1622512174,1609271320,1587393873,1587905815,1617876269,1621784692,1622547456,1590808197,1617097899,1606785927,1590263194,1604621524,1618091922,1618556499,1589951813,1590526708,1613993853,1592534526,1595017369,1595652771,1602157746,1595648044,1599966770,1604746259,1615224427,1600743314,1630246279,1599503159,1605800562,1673505842,1607478848,1624826137,1606455075,1626190649,1625697940,1628727661,1613167765,1610614471,1611091880,1610873808,1662181408,1624324566,1618261520,1615685219,1639061639,1639876120,1617090415,1616206651,1703829166,1619815344,1623702398,1620680377,1622745539,1640663494,1621006406,1644194356,1621532645,1624461398,1649619831,1626145206,1645832615,1624708954,1634308126,1629742771,1649837151,1632827645,1631675948,1633110851,1644654802,1633124904,1648123634,1646373340,1637062307,1634465178,1635833219,1665450601,1665802499,1665799946,1716971726,1636878230,1637158538,1638399691,1682884713,1637535305,1640944887,1638943717,1790687032,1640141642,1641654005,1643767056,1653388515,1647743983,1685208230,1647667885,1689226070,1646543430,1660580635,1646614994,1671408346,1666133434,1646804280,1666851329,1646320529,4188840796,1701079169,1711635617,1650455027,1653332108,1702895945,1681016072,1650469287,1650759043,1663583010,1650825671,1653763052,1680353887,1671221552,1654225932,1651549723,1654675842,1707797424,1747144232,1670477186,1670478684,1656294311,1664299326,1655846544,1654337778,1654580586,1696230039,1658713590,1657351973,1678239123,1657520788,1669057909,1664301736,1660593033,1664208002,1665602184,1666212570,1752293643,1753951037,1755039124,1777591618,1668525247,1669094305,1758899681,1673127249,1675441704,1673703524,1673713548,1673986749,1676259827,1680487429,1678566186,1680893310,1699428990,1740611873,1686932009,1821383659,1684970115,1791110792,1685759340,1689500687,1686546562,1687200670,1688553521,1690275043,1695447703,1691090213,1715689520,1691098723,1692772069,1692840377,1699341888,1695104082,1708518327,1698704933,1720663280,1790314270,1702367930,1699488190,1702753988,1905522025,1709771035,1734033605,1705132930,1704716880,1736162886,1708427812,1739339308,1711849673,1715103616,1712168437,1714208416,1713202109,1717270345,1715142566,1748190004,1748363914,1744655795,1720560682,1715363972,1762999309,1714898908,1715179182,1718378623,1774662915,1720475956,1720728523,1720123038,1717487596,1717473992,1717532186,1717967959,1801744448,1729306147,1743253647,1743250375,1720775257,1728625951,1733014456,1756489130,1733146313,1746140130,1759060668,1734960249,1742871090,1739685944,1762958840,1783513352,1735922800,1740221055,1740225583,1766921276,1766951545,1752659070,1755887706,1743497887,1746108907,1750786440,2407617441,2533306028,1747195640,1747748141,1774852320,1750346012,1750868352,1750979322,1756259224,1755190970,1782204004,1806786898,1778032012,1754019376,1753514740,1754832269,1790575833,1797062405,1755602099,1773844986,1775520089,1777959363,1757012866,1757234605,1961578219,1988371466,1757260759,1759925389,1788793674,1759906561,1759968821,1761043140,1760567160,1811804547,1811860140,1785987431,1763211293,1761028752,1763153408,1762680571,1840868043,1869056469,1764386392,1818698455,'
)
where id_ in (2,3)
;

-- only 2 and 3 get the third part
update test 
set col_ = col_||to_clob(
'1814925259,1844048107,1792923113,1766759279,1806690100,1769099790,1781889076,1767419994,1840873334,1860451690,1869057032,1832297539,1798732309,1777625741,1769504412,2256654733,2256394643,1769294952,1771550966,1773552097,1780825387,1775358335,1831495772,1777950912,1817575825,1778590238,1838491762,1842689273,1809036097,1842691008,1804226456,1778837913,1779109995,1802175163,1797361215,1782177386,1780300688,1783979889,1782182913,1782741969,1804421414,1784397327,1818168758,1786992906,1792081356,1792088712,1786004770,1790345572,1809433204,1815113504,1792147789,1789809441,1796047787,2052143664,1817107737,1817107064,1793983861,1794022214,1822817576,1811874533,1873343889,1866775899,1796519453,1811387402,1811390161,1811389686,1794329867,1798454338,1852540260,1875851020,1800774505,1821743703,1860623035,1821739977,1846153724,1889792452,1886966038,1800887081,3808566599,3940130288,3940136831,1798020921,1914756178,1801865643,1811249875,1799835543,1828917793,1802270135,1800012292,1800532265,1807895881,1812249070,1804106223,1825280927,1803288440,1803816935,1807255080,2018350809,2019138810,1851705279,1907325238,1871335841,1808765462,1809134665,1810437035,1813509873,1810547173,1811326813,1811694658,1824684930,1813787955,1839416942,1818235954,1895818608,1905958320,1830160706,1818228275,1842536407,1818806574,1836790621,1864363952,1817484177,1836665032,1836660198,1906067440,1901970936,1905622709,1818602143,1817971775,1821837825,1849836667,1868981787,1881234294,1881234637,1821288875,1833130648,1826325419,2973158753,1845549940,1830174632,1842407948,1830421553,1829985582,1893281403,1914874048,1889040775,1880361403,1921892126,1931315066,1827486462,1828963796,1829674270,1897254018,1915426413,1899844779,1932515087,1831848686,1831689960,1835308484,1838654429,1835519644,1849474090,1835786806,1908508982,1902791623,1870633645,1832944914,1892062861,1911322479,1871343608,1926558773,1848937114,1849426970,1836057852,1833236489,1833656603,1853711860,1833975396,1860757357,1838043540,1893303429,1893232952,1868373271,1889112786,1835184952,1835791195,1874018090,1871440216,1874342861,1839127975,1854395675,1839672686,3912799648,1932709261,1839473346,1850125810,1841465143,1843159279,1842576914,1843007201,1904067060,1888440163,1846360698,1858511426,1864065464,1874159628,1905554582,1904788564,1848619528,1852033506,1851154589,1855759701,1868417858,1855131342,1877691966,1880931070,1880908960,1861645053,1873708585,1873828632,1929998820,1864080430,1901401422,1898693844,1866675797,1881799571,1863363457,1879150302,1867310018,1913885364,1868061766,1901332941,1901333520,1884062883,1912162181,1867188977,1927263938,1941864872,1867081010,1897661727,1886785734,1868117499,1907251286,1870080439,1887027718,1929998928,1870956156,2150027360,2150307013,1874312074,1880967321,1901284503,1877295727,1911473147,1883166598,1899038584,1893959217,1916254122,1932517625,1893959339,1933595065,1945529144,1942281798,1887151883,1888450314,1894921531,1901818712,1894220580,1909749242,2065657174,1897279003,2060062735,1898400805,1903488534,1904890537,1918506617,1908422848,4457911809,1907237508,1905867088,1913081045,1925547868,1906306816,1909451800,1959470521,1907606907,1925323155,1912783604,1912782165,1909366720,1914761244,1918181121,1914430807,1947239893,1931601005,1913264338,1930650072,1951534568,1930896518,1920306065,1916196520,1916283047,1918255238,1931318996,1931322009,1937810611,1919069583,1927164440,1920305658,1924743213,1946095387,3609531133,3663324518,1931167839,1921962136,1922335417,1922555676,1923532923,1924064543,1930611475,1926184585,1926239192,1926608509,1935074989,1944611992,1932692433,1929319800,1931722999,1932762459,1955720668,1938674808,1939564345,1929449684,1931559090,1950526911,1945032610,1953285923,1935505180,1935753529,1951322279,1935890419,1949922533,1938628712,1950054253,1939514084,1941503687,1943021877,1953597488,1953598822,1942035546,1975810062,1972606764,1941750693,2047638895,1947964583,1975577308,1975577352,1972910374,1972907949,1944325055'
)
where id_ in (2,3)
;

-- only 3 gets the fourth part
update test 
set col_ = col_||to_clob(
',1948673740,1971775559,1959452762,1945820918,1946729992,1948575079,1949406069,1949679905,1951708200,1954659337,2082042164,1973102545,1958566705,1958952936,1962086871,1977320542,1979116386,1984862747,1979189193,1964417653,1976708450,1961770729,1975636620,1968687908,1963362914,1963763171,1968018287,1966719210,2035732281,2055743483,2057969213,2033792616,2053007679,2048122581,1985328064,1969517527,1969024053,1969576592,2187898958,1975517403,1975516319,1977454781,2015317801,1983863928,1975834633,2034294999,2033789600,1979630693,1984176587,1976224303,1990490329,1980772147,2002535750,2489429085,2466487161,2624118025,1981002029,1991863266,1978969289,2012332928,2012365221,1980271916,1982753982,1988228761,1996388928,1990132999,1990458049,1994361024,2017223549,1991726909,1994538500,2012416722,1995300364,2041752227,2041692794,2020875807,1996209164,1996939602,2050771629,2120682448,2000348494,2017919836,2044060252,2000995926,2114066128,2019696323,2005103030,2067148395,2086973457,2003237847,2014747711,2014747747,2018954778,2064226173,2005985054,2014745090,2008082621,2008923234,2010072867,2010514404,2012633060,2039487432,2033957571,2011105958,2011356502,2012736269,2023797663,2034716317,2017649667,2046271657,2689454239,2687105288,2015566644,2027000415,2064253365,2150994549,2099375825,2129560075,2088685497,2016356764,2053453035,2137424877,2100014838,2212083152,2019190552,2019587928,2060814646,2035277035,2023922773,2025007411,2023121822,2026183446,2033549022,2033549052,2055844770,2084427654,2132364379,2108982590,2091656086,2128930838,2116160694,2132361804,2060062678,2035464746,2043640105,2051363476,2045095315,2045355332,2063885164,2046028617,2054661478,2054494010,2048955702,2192802668,2051362845,2057485949,2051364001,2055840260,2051508935,2052590429,2053762179,2052638545,2065638248,2054382409,2054743095,2062269348,2123546644,2125309150,2058818717,2062669598,2066199863,2068830772,2058819844,2056415551,2056608519,2062671380,2058845909,2057221018,2081772205,2060801722,2061287659,2062478863,2066834800,2085488979,2064477479,2066002357,2065065221,2168514653,2203033983,2141245124,2169567082,2080009171,2068723579,2067490582,2084130020,2084130041,2084130066,2109140465,2199630590,2084131233,2084131276,2084131326,2107658933,2074223820,2074223858,2074223903,2199631814,2084133411,2084133432,2084133457,2192930335,2199632895,2192805746,2084136222,2084136318,2084136482,2199633582,2199633363,2084141353,2084141416,2084141492,2072716211,2081963645,2081883280,2127800693,2079921865,2072801933,2073017433,2084148071,2084148205,2088119398,2087106943,2084144453,2084144474,2084144499,2079061390,2079347114,2079968745,2146668286,2146720057,2297343041,2289861797,2137127785,2137121986,2131246609,2168522731,2218105811,2169572607,2141215656,2080595509,2084102284,2334599325,2437306692,2449266675,2431717448,2084447495,2082824852,2168493321,2169570405,2141985628,2189948559,2083538125,2466561164,2719142737,2945921676,3141825913,3292002088,3291653688,2084056119,2567604300,2567807805,2085081472,2085110990,2085132590,2085229311,2085608972,2100508561,2089673053,2127808443,2087766197,2192807025,2088356868,2089076140,2090607399,2090338279,2163837715,2131555978,2210750346,2210774623,2092594582,2092808908,2131280988,2133657963,2122292999,2122300646,2107657219,2108078603,2108206990,2174341948,2235097046,2131258221,2200615407,2224986097,2188144771,2108807285,2155972957,2174601176,2114709209,2294935903,2375448272,2115353212,2319356727,2387339621,2123534389,2116848461,2195339379,2136070544,2169319257,2125885978,2172755624,2116334790,2119033720,2118935563,2118714846,2183651152,2155653835,2118275049,2118299232,2123759318,2233083654,2457607783,2543502171,2517621550,2526399862,2554622538,2603515279,2137005760,2120012384,2159107796,2119478209,2146711869,2123529070,2142543363,2142610303,2120746892,2124046700,2121433481,2121498379,2121554906,2142696324,2124821808,2135745772,2122258033,2122378374,2122384636,2279973128,2123742601,2134364783,2131247889,2155250364'
)
where id_ in (3)
;

-- only 3 gets the last part
update test 
set col_ = col_||to_clob(
',1948673740,1971775559,1959452762,1945820918,1946729992,1948575079,1949406069,1949679905,1951708200,1954659337,2082042164,1973102545,1958566705,1958952936,1962086871,1977320542,1979116386,1984862747,1979189193,1964417653,1976708450,1961770729,1975636620,1968687908,1963362914,1963763171,1968018287,1966719210,2035732281,2055743483,2057969213,2033792616,2053007679,2048122581,1985328064,1969517527,1969024053,1969576592,2187898958,1975517403,1975516319,1977454781,2015317801,1983863928,1975834633,2034294999,2033789600,1979630693,1984176587,1976224303,1990490329,1980772147,2002535750,2489429085,2466487161,2624118025,1981002029,1991863266,1978969289,2012332928,2012365221,1980271916,1982753982,1988228761,1996388928,1990132999,1990458049,1994361024,2017223549,1991726909,1994538500,2012416722,1995300364,2041752227,2041692794,2020875807,1996209164,1996939602,2050771629,2120682448,2000348494,2017919836,2044060252,2000995926,2114066128,2019696323,2005103030,2067148395,2086973457,2003237847,2014747711,2014747747,2018954778,2064226173,2005985054,2014745090,2008082621,2008923234,2010072867,2010514404,2012633060,2039487432,2033957571,2011105958,2011356502,2012736269,2023797663,2034716317,2017649667,2046271657,2689454239,2687105288,2015566644,2027000415,2064253365,2150994549,2099375825,2129560075,2088685497,2016356764,2053453035,2137424877,2100014838,2212083152,2019190552,2019587928,2060814646,2035277035,2023922773,2025007411,2023121822,2026183446,2033549022,2033549052,2055844770,2084427654,2132364379,2108982590,2091656086,2128930838,2116160694,2132361804,2060062678,2035464746,2043640105,2051363476,2045095315,2045355332,2063885164,2046028617,2054661478,2054494010,2048955702,2192802668,2051362845,2057485949,2051364001,2055840260,2051508935,2052590429,2053762179,2052638545,2065638248,2054382409,2054743095,2062269348,2123546644,2125309150,2058818717,2062669598,2066199863,2068830772,2058819844,2056415551,2056608519,2062671380,2058845909,2057221018,2081772205,2060801722,2061287659,2062478863,2066834800,2085488979,2064477479,2066002357,2065065221,2168514653,2203033983,2141245124,2169567082,2080009171,2068723579,2067490582,2084130020,2084130041,2084130066,2109140465,2199630590,2084131233,2084131276,2084131326,2107658933,2074223820,2074223858,2074223903,2199631814,2084133411,2084133432,2084133457,2192930335,2199632895,2192805746,2084136222,2084136318,2084136482,2199633582,2199633363,2084141353,2084141416,2084141492,2072716211,2081963645,2081883280,2127800693,2079921865,2072801933,2073017433,2084148071,2084148205,2088119398,2087106943,2084144453,2084144474,2084144499,2079061390,2079347114,2079968745,2146668286,2146720057,2297343041,2289861797,2137127785,2137121986,2131246609,2168522731,2218105811,2169572607,2141215656,2080595509,2084102284,2334599325,2437306692,2449266675,2431717448,2084447495,2082824852,2168493321,2169570405,2141985628,2189948559,2083538125,2466561164,2719142737,2945921676,3141825913,3292002088,3291653688,2084056119,2567604300,2567807805,2085081472,2085110990,2085132590,2085229311,2085608972,2100508561,2089673053,2127808443,2087766197,2192807025,2088356868,2089076140,2090607399,2090338279,2163837715,2131555978,2210750346,2210774623,2092594582,2092808908,2131280988,2133657963,2122292999,2122300646,2107657219,2108078603,2108206990,2174341948,2235097046,2131258221,2200615407,2224986097,2188144771,2108807285,2155972957,2174601176,2114709209,2294935903,2375448272,2115353212,2319356727,2387339621,2123534389,2116848461,2195339379,2136070544,2169319257,2125885978,2172755624,2116334790,2119033720,2118935563,2118714846,2183651152,2155653835,2118275049,2118299232,2123759318,2233083654,2457607783,2543502171,2517621550,2526399862,2554622538,2603515279,2137005760,2120012384,2159107796,2119478209,2146711869,2123529070,2142543363,2142610303,2120746892,2124046700,2121433481,2121498379,2121554906,2142696324,2124821808,2135745772,2122258033,2122378374,2122384636,2279973128,2123742601,2134364783,2131247889,2155250364'
)
where id_ in (3)
;

select length(col_),id_ from test;
-- LENGTH(COL_) ID_
--  3965          1
-- 11885          2
-- 19805          3

select * from test
        where col_ like 'step A: 1514 JBPM_TASKINSTANCE cancelled. IDs%';
-- 3 results

select * from test
            where col_ like 'step A: % JBPM_TASKINSTANCE cancelled. IDs%';
-- (!!!) 2 results
```

Comment: in 18 there in both cases 3 results *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=467564d6ab68995bf71bc2209fc1f751)* . it must be a special feature of version 11 :)

Comment: @hotfix thank you. interesting. if I switch your fiddle to 11g, it's only 2 rows. when on 18, it's 3 rows ^^

Comment: for whatever reason it does not work with a colon. have a look *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a08df56fa0e6667afddb41ad272d4e3d)*

Comment: but the colon character itself can't be the reason. Here is the same problem with a * instead of :      
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=236c7ce77c4fe12cc070e68f7657d533

Comment: in the support database of oracle there are some entries to a bug(Bug 14402514), which is fixed with 11.2.0.4

Comment: thank you hotfix. can you explain to me how you found the bug on support.oracle.com? i can see it shows up searching for 'like clob'. I searched for 'like clob wildcard' which does not show it (at least not in first few results). what's your magic? ^^

Comment: at the top  of the search result page you can use a filter. click on bug and you will see the results you need

Comment: omg. i thought that that 'Bug' is greyed out means that it did not find any. but in fact it means that it does not search for it until I click it ^^ tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

**LIKE with wildcard (%) not working on 4000char+ clob column**

**TRUE** for 11G

**FALSE** for 12c and above

For 11g You can use the following query to fulfill your requirement:

```
select * from test
            where dbms_lob.instr(col_,' JBPM_TASKINSTANCE cancelled. IDs') > dbms_lob.instr(col_,'step A: ');
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a73d798b406d6e9e10868d2edd84e70f)

POC:

11G: [Error with 11G - Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d7ae23f401534b3c40d31fe98a25aea)

18C/12C: [Working as expected - Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d7ae23f401534b3c40d31fe98a25aea)

Comment: the statement is not quite correct. It works, but not in all cases

Comment: Yes, I can understand your concern. I am just trying to show you the workaround for the case mentioned by you in question. :)

Comment: thank you. i was not looking for a workaround though, but fur the rule regarding when like can be used on clobs. and the rule seems to be to use it but to know the bugs that exist around it (in 11.2.0.3 at least.)